# Trying to resolve an "invalid use of Null" in VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

Quick snippet first:

```
Dim GUID As String
Dim givenNames, familyName, preferredName, gender, comments, carer, medicareNumber, patientNumber As String
Dim dob As Variant
Dim deceased, resolved, consultNotes As Boolean
Dim age As Variant

givenNames = Null
familyName = Null
preferredName = Null
gender = Null
dob = Null
comments = Null
deceased = False
resolved = False
carer = Null
age = Null
consultNotes = False
patientNumber = Null ' This is where I get the error
```

Any idea why this last variable would be the one to trip up? I've assigned Null to a bunch of other strings without any errors.

Comment: patientNumber is the only variable you've defined as a string.  You have to specify the type for *each* variable: you can't define a comma-separated list of variables like you have in your code.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In VBA/VB6, strings cannot be set to Null; only Variants can be set to null. In addition, when you declare variables inline comma-separated like in the question, only the last one will be typed as string; all of the others are typed as variants. To declare them on one line as a type you have to include the type

```
Dim a As String, Dim b As String ...
```

That's why it makes sense to just declare them on a single line.

(Btw, it should be noted that `deceased, resolved` are also typed as variants for the same reason.)

Answer (score 9):

The reason that it succeeds for `givenNames`, etc. is that you have unwittingly defined them as Variant type.  It fails for `patientNumber`, because you successfully defined that as a `String`, and strings do not accept Null values.

Within a `Dim` statement, the `As <type>` clause applies to each individual variable in the list, so by putting it only at the end of the list, you applied the explicit type only to the last-listed variable.  The implicit type of `Variant` is applied to the others.

Comment: @HorusKol - np - glad we could help.

Answer (score 1):

When I ran into that problem without knowing about the implicit type of `Variant`, I was able to use the work around of defining an extra variable such as `BogusVariable` at the end of the `Dim` statement list.

Answer (score 0):

in VBA strings uses `vbNullString` value for `Null`